# Transimpedance AMP, Active HPF, phototransistor

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, photodiode, phototransistor

So this is the part where I would like the phototransistor (TEMT6000X01) to be able to clearly capture an LED with a frequency flashing on and off at 1kHz. So what I have here is a transimpedance amplifier (AD823) with Rf at 100k because the typical collector light current for high illumination is 50uA V = 50uA * 100k giving 5V. Would the capacitor be okay for this?

Second I have a high pass filter allowing frequencies from around 995Hz upwards. Does it seem correct?

Thirdly, since the maximum output from the TIA is 5V, is it necessary to have a non inverting amplifier (AD823) to amplify the signal?

Once passed the peak detector, the output will be connected to the Arduino.

What are your thoughts?

Datasheet for TEMT6000X01: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/112b/0900766b8112bb21.pdf

Datasheet for AD823: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD823.pdf

[image]

Comment: This circuit is odd to me, I would expect U2 to have some level of bias voltage across it to move the signal amplitude to more than the dark current, most circuits would instead of having the emitter to ground, would have it to something like -1V to -5V

C2 is acting as a low pass filter, not sure if that is intentional,

Comment: Hi Reroute, I don't really understand what you mean by that the bias voltage across to move the signal more than the dark current. It seems to be an NPN where the base changes on light intensity and emitter connected to ground? What is the purpose of C2? I don't understand why people add a capacitor parallel to R2

Comment: right now, if light is shone on U2, the collector current does not significantly change, by having a bias voltage across the collector and emitter the change in current is much larger, allowing for a clearer signal.

Comment: I understand your point, in your view, how would you design it? Have you got a sketch?

Comment: Easiest way to introduce a bias, would be instead of connecting pin 5 of U3.1 to ground, connect it to a resistor divider to get 2-5V at that input, this will mean the op amp will handle the biasing.

Comment: C2 reduces the bandwidth of that op amp, and means the output moves more slowly,

Comment: Okay I will see what I can do. Is in necessary in this case to have a non inverting amplifier?

Comment: Hi there I took your suggestion onboard to take away feedback capacitor. Should my new circuit work? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455789/transimpedance-amp-active-hpf-phototdiode-updated

Comment: flip the diode around, and add a voltage to pin 5 of the left op amp to bias it, the fastest mode of operation of these photo diodes is reverse bias.