# Transimpedance AMP, Active HPF, phototdiode (updated)

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, filter, photodiode, transimpedance

The original post is here [Transimpedance AMP, Active HPF, phototransistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454989/transimpedance-amp-active-hpf-phototransistor?noredirect=1#comment1144804_454989)

I decided to change back to a photodiode instead of a phototransistor since I have used one for a similar experiment in the past. I also took the suggestion to remove the feedback capacitor.

In this setup I am using a VISHAY BPW34. Should the Rf be good enough for good readings? And is non inverting high pass good enough to pass only 995Hz frequency and amplify the signal? Should this setup work in terms of op amp and output?

[image]

Comment: That 160 Ohm resistor may be a heavy load; I suggest 1.6Kohm, and keep the C1 at 1uF (that becomes 100Hz F3dB for the DC_blocking, and you avoid the 3dB signal amplitude penalty). You will not --- ever --- succeed in only passing 995Hz, and rejecting 994 and 996. No reasonable filter can be that sharp. With high effort, you may achieve Q=10 filter. How strong is your signal? Is there any interference? any optical noise? or just circuit noise (random KT) and VDD trash?

Comment: Hi there, it needs to be around 995Hz which means I do need 160. I know you will never get the exact filter but that's real life. My signal outputs maximum around 0.5V since Iphotodiode is about 50uA and feedback 10k which gives 0.5V. I want to keep the noise low if possible. After the filter, it amplifies to about 5V since it's a non inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the diode polarity, and add a voltage e.g. 1-5V to pin 5 of U3.1, this will give you a faster response time,

Often called reverse-bias, it has less effective capacitance than the normal polarity.

Answer (score 1):

> Should this setup work in terms of op amp and output?

No it won't work. The photodiode produces a current that flows into the anode and out from the cathode and this means that the front-end op-amp has to drive its output negative to keep the op-amp inputs balanced at 0 volts. This requires a negative supply on the op-amp and you don't have one.

If you swapped the polarity of the photodiode you would get it working to some extent but the very lowest of signals won't register because the op-amp can only swing down to about 25 mV above 0 volts.

Comment: A down vote - can anyone see a reason?